# Wordpress search form action

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I need to do a custom search function in my wordpress page, some javascript codes needed to put into header and use wordpress search form to call that function.

Under the theme folder of wordpress, I have added some javascript codes between   tag in header.php

```
<head>
  <script>
      var test123456 = function() {
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        }

     </script>

</head>
```

The default theme searchform.php was:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I would like to ask how do I call that javascript function by searchform.php ?

my form part:

```
<form action="javascript:test123456()">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" id="curlinput">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

many thanks and appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
<form onsubmit="test123456()">
<div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks aje,
i need to delete action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>"  , right ?

Comment: Yes, and also call the JavaScript function on submit.

Comment: Thanks aje ~~ appreciated !

Comment: Sorry that I still have a  question is ..........this will run javascript function directly on the CURRENT PAGE (not search page)  when click the "search button" , that's mean it will not redirect to search.php . so, what should i do if  I want to keep the default form action (  action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>"  )  and run the javascript function on search.php ?   many thanks ~~~

Comment: In that case call your function on page load like `$(document).ready(function(){ YOUR_FUNCTION() })` in `search.php`

Comment: thanks aje ... but no luck it not work :(
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    curltest()
})
</script>

Comment: the javascript function i had put inside header.php between <head></head> already

Comment: share demo URL if you can.

Comment: sorry aje ... i still have not apply domain and hosting yet, i just running it by xampp..

Comment: Hi aje... i have post the question with my codes here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083669/wordpress-google-custom-search-by-search-form-again

Answer (score 0):

You can put form line this.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="test123456();">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

OR like below

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="javascript:test123456()">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

If you also want to set action file then try below code.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" onsubmit="test123456();">
        <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Sorry that I still have a  question is ..........this will run javascript function directly on the CURRENT PAGE (not search page)  when click the "search button" , that's mean it will not redirect to search.php . so, what should i do if  I want to keep the default form action (  action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>"  )  and run the javascript function on search.php ?   many thanks ~~~

Comment: Hi Jalpa, ... i have post the question with my codes here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083669/wordpress-google-custom-search-by-search-form-again

Comment: @lingmak Please check comment on your new question.